# Sed Command: Searching pattern with wildcard before and after the target string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

Content of sample.xml is like the one below.

```
<Name="com.name1.sample.date" level="ERROR"/>
<Name="com.name2.test" level="WARNING">
<Name="com.name3.type.yeah.trace" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
```

I am trying to use sed and just replace the value of the "level paramater" on all lines.
However, using (*) as wildcard is not working for pattern matching.

I'd like the output to be like the one below.

```
<Name="com.name1.sample.date" level="INFO"/>
<Name="com.name2.test" level="WARN">
<Name="com.name3.type.yeah.trace" additivity="false" level="UPDATE">
```

Basically:
From this pattern 
    `*level="<pattern>"*`
To this pattern 
    `*level="<updated>"*`

Where the * could be any pattern.

I did some research here and was able to make it work for wildcard at the beginning  but not at the end so I am doing a special handling for each pattern that has a different ending. Below is my code.

`sed 's|="'"$logger_type"'".*|="'"$logger_type"'" level="'"$update_check"'"/>|g'`

Where $logger_type is the name being referenced, and its level should be updated to whatever the content of $update_check

Comment: That doesn't look like valid XML... (And you should be using a XML aware tool like `xmlstarlet` or whatever to work with XML, not `sed`.)

Comment: @Shawn it looks like a part of log4j.xml or alike, there's an "envelope" in a real XML-file.

If that's true, then `sed` is "good enough" to adjust file contents (the structure is rather simple).

Comment: Do you need to perform a single replacement or a series of replacements using a complex set of rules (e.g. the level for `com.name1.sample.date` should be set to one value, the level `com.name2.test` to another and so on and so forth)?

Comment: you are correct. series of replacement.

Comment: The rules and flow of the update is already working, only that I can't create a universal sed command for each situation (each line in the sample is a different situation) that would take care of the update. The sample file above is just a snippet of the code to show the differences of each situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically:
>   From this pattern 
>       `*level="<pattern>"*`
>   To this pattern 
>       `*level="<updated>"*`

Since your input is line-oriented, we can use `"logger_type"` as an *address* *regexp* to process only the lines matching the regular expression; therewith we can simplify the substitution pattern to only specify `level="…"` and leave other attributes (like `additivity`) as they are.

```
sed /\"$logger_type'"/s/level="\w*"/level="'$update_check\"/ sample.xml
```